# Automated-Testing with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, recording, testcase, automated-tests

I am working on data driving a coded UI test (using Visual Studio 2013). The test is very simple at this point

1. sign in to a website,
2. Click on 2 links
3. Select a value form the drop down list and then signs out.

The steps 1, 2 are working fine, but all my runs fail due to the error below.

> Test method CodedUITestProject17.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw
>   exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details:  TechnologyName:  'Web' ControlType: 
>   'Custom' ClassName:  'Internet Explorer_Server'

Code:

```
// Select '1' in 'Rooms' combo box 
uIRoomsComboBox.SelectedItem = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIRoomsComboBoxSelectedItem; 

// Click list item 
Mouse.Click(uIItemListItem, new Point(12, 7)); 

// Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;
```

if anyone can help solve the problem..?

Comment: Can you include the code being run? Judging by the error message, it seems it cannot find the UI control you're trying to interact with

Comment: Hi, this is the code:                                              // Select '1' in 'Rooms' combo box
            uIRoomsComboBox.SelectedItem = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIRoomsComboBoxSelectedItem;

            // Click list item
            Mouse.Click(uIItemListItem, new Point(12, 7));

            // Set flag to allow play back to continue if non-essential actions fail. (For example, if a mouse hover action fails.)
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.ContinueOnError = true;

Comment: When using CodedUI recording, which is just a clunky tool, you are also getting the current state of the application being recorded.  What this means is that upon playback the state is not necessarily there.  Codedui uses a very interesting way to "Break in" to another process and control it, in short the recorder tool records strict GUI hierarchies that are almost certainly not there on playback.  There are some tricks one of them being you need to insert a wait until control appears or something similar. Try that first and let us know if it works.